# Entropy of squeezed vacuum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, squeezed-states

**Objective**: I am trying to familiarise myself with quantum entropy for squeezed vacuum states.

**Context**: As a previous excercise, I have evaluated von Neumann entropy $\mathcal{S}(\widehat{\rho})=-\text{Tr}(\widehat{\rho}\log(\widehat{\rho}))$  for thermal states, since the density matrix for thermal states is known result (within the framework of quantum mechanics):

$\widehat{\rho}=\frac{1}{Z}\underset{n}{\sum}\exp\left(-n\hbar\omega/k_{B}T\right)\left|n\right\rangle \left\langle n\right|$

where $Z$ is the partition function:

$Z=\text{Tr}\left(\underset{n}{\sum}\exp\left(-n\hbar\omega/k_{B}T\right)\left|n\right\rangle \left\langle n\right|\right)$

Thus, von Neumann entropy is derived.

$\mathcal{S}(\widehat{\rho})=-\text{Tr}(\widehat{\rho}\log(\widehat{\rho}))=-\underset{n}{\sum}\lambda_{n}\log\left(\lambda_{n}\right)=-\underset{n}{\sum}\frac{\exp\left(-n\hbar\omega/k_{B}T\right)}{Z}\log\left(\frac{\exp\left(-n\hbar\omega/k_{B}T\right)}{Z}\right)$

where I has used that the density matrix is diagional ([see this link](https://www.physik.uzh.ch/local/teaching/SPI301/LV-2013-Help/lvanlsconcepts.chm/lvac_matrix_logarithm.html)).

**Problem**: I want to evaluate the entropy for squeezed vacuum states, but it seems that I am *mixing* the concepts of **superposition** and **mixed states**. From *[Loudon, R. (2000). The quantum theory of light. OUP Oxford.](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&lr=&id=AEkfajgqldoC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=%20The%20Quantum%20Theory%20of%20Light%20-%203rd%20ed%20Oxford%20Science%20Publications&ots=JnJNZosKDx&sig=5FB_xj4TUGcQwyALJVfoTuaUjno#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, page 201, chapter 5:

> [...] the number-state expansion of the squeezed vacuum state [...]
> is:
>
> $\left|\zeta\right
> > =\sqrt{\text{sech}\left(s\right)}\underset{n}{\sum}\frac{\sqrt{2n!}}{n!}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(i\vartheta\right)\tanh\left(s\right)\right]^{n}\left|2n\right\rangle$

If I have understand the point well, the density matrix for a squeezed vacuum state depicts a pure-state: $\widehat{\rho}=\left|\zeta\right\rangle \left\langle \zeta\right|$, and therefore the entropy of such a system is 0. However, when I'm trying to convince myself via algebra:

$\widehat{\rho}=\text{sech}\left(s\right)\underset{n}{\sum}\frac{\sqrt{2n!}}{n!}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(i\vartheta\right)\tanh\left(s\right)\right]^{n}\left|2n\right\rangle \left(\underset{n}{\sum}\frac{\sqrt{2m!}}{m!}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(i\vartheta\right)\tanh\left(s\right)\right]^{m}\right)^{*}\left\langle 2m\right|$

When I continue that path, I find that the determinant of the density matrix is 0 (and I do not know if this is a result to argument that the entropy is 0).

EDIT:

**Question**: How to verify with the last equation I wrote that the entropy of a squeezed vacuum state is 0?

It seems that I am missing some crucial point at doing this algebra, and confusing mixed states with superposition. Any assistance in this matter is welcome.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Why are you calculating the determinant? In the Fock basis the density operators of the squeezed state would have zeros for all uneven Fock states. These zeros would give a zero determinant.

Comment: @flippiefanus I think I am not familiar with Fock basis, I asked myself if von Neumann entropy could be obtained by using simple algebra. I am evaluating the determinant since I want to evaluate the logarithm of a matrix (log(A) = V(lnλ)V-1.), following the information in the provided link:

https://www.physik.uzh.ch/local/teaching/SPI301/LV-2013-Help/lvanlsconcepts.chm/lvac_matrix_logarithm.html

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but yes, the von Neumann entropy of a pure state is always zero: By functional calculus, write the entropy in terms of the eigenvalues of the density matrix: $S(\rho)=\ldots$? --if you have this, then just make use of the fact that a pure state has only one non-zero eigenvalue (which equals one).

Comment: @TobiasFünke You are right, I think the question was not posed correctly. I have edited the last part of the post. I think that your comment is insightful, I will think about it.